# How to use MATLAB functions in Visual C++?

Tags: matlab, visual-c++

I'm want to use a MATLAB function in visual C++ program.

I know that I'll have to use .dll, .lib, and .h files that I've extracted from MATLAB function.

Question: How can I use the extracted .dll, .lib, and, .h files to call this function in visual C++?
Please don't refer me to any links. I've tried them many times. please notice how to do it.
Here is my MATLAB function:

```
function [ Integ ] = integral( x , a,b )
Integ = int(x,a,b);
end
```

And i want a VC++ program like this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Integral.h"
int main(){
 int a =1;
 int b=0;
 syms x,hg, resault;
 hg = x^2;
 resault = Integral (hg , a,b);

}
```

Comment: You can't call it like that.  The only way that you can call MATLAB code inside a C++ function is if you write a MEX wrapper and call it within MATLAB.  You also can call MATLAB native functions directly in the C++ code, but that also requires that you write a MEX wrapper.  Unfortunately, what you want is not possible, though it would make our lives easier.

Comment: How can i create MEX and how use it?

Comment: Great tutorial here: http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/ee264/Fall11/cmex.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access MATLAB from Visual Studio and Eclipse through the MATLAB engine interface.  As long as you MATLAB installed you just need to set the right paths in your project settings and link in 3 library files.

Here is a link to the description and setup.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-matlab-engine.html
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100603-how-can-i-compile-a-matlab-engine-application-using-microsoft-visual-studio-9-0-or-10-0

Once you link Visual Studio / Eclipse to MATLAB you can do call MATLAB functions, plots, scripts, and pass variables back and forth (see below):

engEvalString(ep, "cd c:/MATLAB_Demos");        // Change to active directory
engEvalString(ep, "img = imread('image_2.jpg');");  // Read in image to process
engEvalString(ep, "Igray = rgb2gray(img);");        // Convert to grayscale
engEvalString(ep, "figure; imshow(Igray);");        // Display image to verify
engEvalString(ep, "Thresh_Fn(1)");             // Call MATLAB scripts/functions and pass arguments
engPutVariable(ep, "output", output);

Igray = engGetVariable(ep, "Igray");   // Pointer to MATLAB variable
const uint8_t* Ip = static_cast(mxGetData(Igray));    // Pointer in C variable

Hope that helps,

Andy

Image Processing Applications
- MathWorks